# I cant config multipple remote directories bypass with Spring Inbound Integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, ftp, integration

I have tried such configuration of outbound Integration

```
  @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "fetchRecursive")
public interface Gateway {
    public List<File> fetchFiles(String remoteDir);
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow polled() {
    return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(() -> gateway(),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fetchRecursive")
public FtpOutboundGateway gateway() {
    // Create a recursive MGET gateway that gets the remote directory from the payload
    FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(sessionFactory(), "mget", "payload");
    gateway.setOptions("-R");
    gateway.setLocalDirectory(new File(localDirectory));
    gateway.setFilter(files -> Arrays.stream(files)
            .filter(file -> patterns.stream()
                    .filter(pattern -> !file.getName().endsWith(pattern))
                    .findFirst()
                    .isPresent())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return gateway;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> sessionFactory() {
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(defaultFtpSessionFactory());
}

@Bean
DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPassword(pw);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setUsername(username);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setHost(host);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPort(port);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setClientMode(FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE);
    return defaultFtpSessionFactory;
}
```

This code can bypass all remote directories, but it doesnt rewrite dowloaded files in target local folder and it doesnt downloading newcomer files from remote ftp.

I also have tried such way of configuring:

```
 @Bean
DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPassword(pw);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setUsername(username);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setHost(host);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPort(port);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setClientMode(FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE);
    return defaultFtpSessionFactory;
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow inbound(DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSf) {
    List<String> remoteDirectories = Arrays.asList("/GRIB2/COMPRESSED/EGRR/T+06",
            "/GRIB2/COMPRESSED/EGRR/T+09", "/GRIB2/COMPRESSED/EGRR/T+12");

        FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec spec = Ftp
                .inboundAdapter(ftpSf)
                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                .filter(files -> Arrays.stream(files)
                        .filter(file -> patterns.stream()
                                .filter(pattern -> !file.getName().endsWith(pattern))
                                .findFirst()
                                .isPresent())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

//                    .remoteDirectory(dir)
.remoteDirectory(remoteDirectories.get(2))
.deleteRemoteFiles(false)
.localDirectory(localDirectory);

```
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(spec, pc -> pc.poller(pm -> pm.fixedRate(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
                .handle((file, messageHeaders) -> {
                    messageHeaders
                            .entrySet().stream().distinct()
                            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("file_name"))
                            .filter(entry -> String.valueOf(entry.getValue()).contains("T+")));
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
}
```

}

But such configuration doesnt bypass multipple remote directories.

And also I have tried such configuration:

```
    @Bean
DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPassword(pw);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setUsername(username);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setHost(host);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPort(port);
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setClientMode(FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE);
    return defaultFtpSessionFactory;
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow inbound(DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSf) {
    List<String> remoteDirectories = Arrays.asList("/GRIB2/COMPRESSED/EGRR/T+06",
            "/GRIB2/COMPRESSED/EGRR/T+09", "/GRIB2/COMPRESSED/EGRR/T+12");

        FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec spec = Ftp
                .inboundAdapter(ftpSf)
                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                .filter(files -> Arrays.stream(files)
                        .filter(file -> patterns.stream()
                                .filter(pattern -> !file.getName().endsWith(pattern))
                                .findFirst()
                                .isPresent())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

//                    .remoteDirectory(dir)
.remoteDirectory(remoteDirectories.get(2))
.deleteRemoteFiles(false)
.localDirectory(localDirectory);

```
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(spec, pc -> pc.poller(pm -> pm.fixedRate(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
                .handle(Ftp.outboundGateway(defaultFtpSessionFactory(),
                                AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MGET, "payload")
                        //.regexFileNameFilter("(.*n.txt)")
                        .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                        .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE)
                        .localDirectoryExpression("'/localDirectory/' + #remoteDirectory"))
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
}
```

}

But this one have the same problem? it doesnt bypass multipple dirs.

Can anybody help me to config Integration flow with FTP to bypass multipple directories with polling request for upcomming new files?
Or maybe there is some possibility config sevral channels each one per remote directory, or maybe I am wrong?